# Trying to put points on a chart using a SharePoint list and Highcharts

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, highcharts

This screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmYHi.jpg - shows the following items

a) what I'm currently getting (no data points)

b) what I would like my results to look like

c) what my SharePoint list looks like

(Sorry, I don't have enough stackOverflow points to post pictures yet)

Below is the code I currently have

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
 var yearmontharray = [];
 var valuesarray = [];
 
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,
  listName: "List",
  CAMLViewFields: "<viewfields><fieldref Name='Title' /><fieldref Name='values' /></ViewFields>",
  CAMLQuery: "<query><orderby><fieldref Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    var yearmonth = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
    var values = Math.round($(this).attr("ows_values"));
 
    yearmontharray.push(yearmonth);
    valuesarray.push(values);
   });
  }
 });
  
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Total values',
                x: -20
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'This chart shows value from SharePoint',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: yearmontharray
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'values'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'values',
                data: valuesarray
            }]
        });
 
 
  
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include contraction of chart inside complete function. Otherwise the call to **Hightchart** are made BEFORE getting data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var yearmontharray = [];
    var valuesarray = [];

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "List",
        CAMLViewFields: "<viewfields><fieldref Name='Title' /><fieldref Name='values' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: "<query><orderby><fieldref Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                var yearmonth = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                var values = Math.round($(this).attr("ows_values"));

                yearmontharray.push(yearmonth);
                valuesarray.push(values);
            });
            // Inside complete func <-----
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Total values',
                    x: -20
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'This chart shows value from SharePoint',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: yearmontharray
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'values'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'values',
                    data: valuesarray
                }]
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Max.  I'm fairly new to working with any kind of code.  How would I go about putting the contraction of chart inside complete function?

Comment: I've already done it, copy and paste the code. Remember to mark answer if work.

Comment: Pasted the new code, but still not getting any values on the graph

Comment: Can you post the working code ? Under the comment `//Inside ...` add `console.log(valuesarray);` and see on browser console if there are data.

Comment: Here is the console output: http://imgur.com/locyLKX  It looks like I'm getting a 400 Bad Request error, which may be the root of my problem.  Not sure how I would resolve that either.

Comment: I think you must verify the CAML query on third part tool [Caml Query](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=caml%20query)

Comment: Max, I removed the CAML query line, and it worked!  Thanks so much for the help.  Can you tell me how you came to the conclusion that it was something to do with that line?

Comment: Sharepoint experience and for error 400 bad request; this means that request successfully reach the server but this something (bad) appends, I then realized that the query was wrong. Advice: before to write down to the js any query test it on tools.